# Calculate coefficient w*

Tags: linear-regression

I'm learning ML from Bishop's book. But I don't know that How should I calculate w* in the below picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked into the book. It was an example of the data that is presented in Fig 1.4. [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) is a good package to derive the sum of squares fit to the data. This is an optimization problem. Look at the notes section of `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`. I think the data is not given (you can digitize it!). The book is showing some qualitative behavior to give some intuition.

[image]

Comment: I want to understand the problem from the mathematical point of view.

Comment: Sure, this is an optimization problem. Have you looked at the notes section of `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, to add the comment to your answer. I accept it.